# Clarify that careers profiles are not available to all on login

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, user-interface

I decided to checkout and "create a profile" on careers today, only to find that I can't do that.

If you goto careers.stackoverflow.com here's what you see:

> What’s your next career move? Stack Overflow Careers has the best job listings from great
> companies, whether you’re looking for opportunities at a start up or Fortune 500. You can
> search our job listings or create a profile and let employers find you.

Except, it seems that you can't "create a profile" without an invitation.
Which is unclear even after going through the pain of logging in.

Contradictory to this is the fact that once logged in you see a section titled "Your profile", with a link that says "view & manage your profile...".

Click the link and you see what looks like an FAQ, where you see the *first* mention of anything to do with an invite in the form:

> How do I request an invite?
>
> Yes, we have a place for that .

So after I've logged in and clicked, "view & manage your profile...", I *guess* your telling me that I need to request an invite to ... create my profile, which apparently I already have since under the section titled, "Your profile", I've clicked "view & manage your profile...".

Looks like the UI here needs a major clean up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.